# ¿Como validar que un usuario especifico visualizo una notificación (mysql)?

Tags: mysql

En `MySQL` tengo 5 tablas, `usuario`, `grupo`, `usuario_grupo`, `deberes`, `comentarios`,...

`usuario_grupo` es la *relación* entre `usuario` y `grupo`, `deberes` tiene *relación* con el `grupo` y `comentarios` *relación* con los `deberes.`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que cuando un usuario de un grupo realize un comentario a un deber, se le **notifique a todos los usuarios DEL MISMO GRUPO**....

**PROBLEMA**

Si agrego un campo que se llame `estado` en la `tabla comentario` solo lo podra visualizar y actualizar automáticamente quien lo crea y no lo podran ver los otros usuarios al momento de hacer la consulta.

> ¿Como puedo entonces hacer que todos los usuarios tengan su propio
>   estado de vista de comentarios?

Es decir, el usuario 1 publico "un nuevo deber", entonces, cuando el usuario 2 o 3 o 4 o 5 (los que existan), inicien sesión, lo puedan ver,y automaticamente se genere un estado de visto **unicamente para ese usuario**....

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo más normal sería añadir una nueva tabla con un nombre como "comentarios_vistos" y campos:

- id
- comentario_id (FK)
- usuario_id (FK)

y uno más si quieres guardar la fecha/hora en que el comentario fue visto.

Otra opción más simple sería añadir otro campo a "comentarios", donde guardar un string que vaya concatenando los IDs de los usuarios que ven el comentario, pero dentro del modelo relacional parece más correcta la primera opción.

Comment: Hola @Orici gracias por tomarte tu tiempo, mira he hecho algo parecido agregrando una un campo mas llamado "estado" tipo boolean, el problema que tengo es, como cargar los ids del comentarios a esa tabla "comentarios_vistas", ya que la idea es que en un boton muestre la cantidad (ejemplo "icono(5)") de comentarios que el usuario no ha visto(0) y apenas de click se actualizen a (1) y muestra la informacion...

Comment: @JDavid en lo que preguntas estás mezclando dos cosas: el diseño de la BD y la lógica que tienes que seguir por programación para mantener ese diseño. Lo que te dice Orici en la respuesta es un diseño correcto, y no hace falta un booleano para saber qué usuarios vieron qué comentarios, sencillamente si haces una consulta filtrando por `usuario_id` y `comentario_id`, si no te trae datos significa que ese usuario no vio ese comentario. Para el código, te toca a ti crear un programa en el que, tan pronto el usuario lea el comentario `x`, se registren en la tabla su id y el id del comentario.